# Where can I add new WPSE tags?

Tags: support

Maybe I'm having a moment of blindness or stupidity, but I can't for the life of me find where I can add a new tag.  I thought I had enough rep, maybe that's where I'm wrong.

What I wanted to do was add a tag for [visual-composer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-composer) with what seems a fairly standard excerpt: "**NOTE** Support for this plugin is off-topic. Support questions should be asked on the plugin's support page."

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I may have been misguided in my intent, but does that make this a bad question? A bit of feedback on the down vote would be helpful. I won't bite :-)

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but just as an fyi, downvotes on meta are different - they indicate agreement/disagreement, not that it's a bad/good question. The downvote was probably just someone saying 'I don't agree with creating this tag'.

Comment: Ah. Got you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found out, new tags are created by using them. **But** every new tag must be useful for our site. Creating a tag for something that's off-topic is against that idea.

Please remove this tag or open a new topic, and explain why it would be useful.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I'd assumed from seeing other tags and their excerpts that this was a way of flagging such off-topic posts more readily. Someone approved it. Where do I delete it?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook is right - we do have a lot of tags for off-topic subjects. IMO they both help alert users that something is off-topic, and help us find and clean up off-topic questions. So it's understandable to go and create another. Given [this post](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4184/excluding-meta-commentary-from-tag-wikis) however, it seems the community consenus is not for using tags to note off-topic plugins etc. As an aside - Andy, you can delete the tag by editing the post again and removing it - tags with no questions are then auto-deleted daily.

Answer (score 6):

Well I kind of found out while I was posting the question.  I'd written the tag name I wanted in an edit to a question, which has been approved and once the tag was accepted then I could get to edit the excerpt.  I need a rep of 20,000 to make edits without approval, which I don't have a problem with.

Wasn't intuitive, but now I know :-)